# Vlookup doesnt read mixture of Alphabet and Numbers eg: 1T902462K01

Tags: excel, vlookup

i have a table as below and i wanted to compare result using Vlookup.

```
    A     | B     | C
-------------------------
1 | ID    | Name  | Lot
-------------------------
2 | 70100 | Krenn | VF849062
-------------------------
3 | 70101 | Georg | VE803354
-------------------------
4 | 70102 | Mohd  | VE803354
```

However `=VLOOKUP(C2,A1:C4,1,FALSE)` will result `#N/A`

Any advise?

Regards,
Zaiem

Comment: The value you're looking up needs to be in the first column of the lookup table.

Comment: This is because the value in **C2** *(VF849062)* can't be found in column **A**.

Comment: I agree with Tim Williams. My understanding is when you use VLOOKUP you need to have the lookup column as the first column and all other columns where you want to search to the right. So my recommendation is to take a look at INDEX + MATCH function. That will solve your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the Index/Match suggested in the comments. It goes like this:

```
=index(A1:A4,match(F1,C1:C4,0))
```

in words: find the value of F1 in the range C1 to C4 and return the value from column A for the same row.

Your Vlookup formula references C2, which does not make sense if column C is the column where you perform the lookup.